# DotNetOpenAuth OP customisation for authentication

Tags: openid, customization, dotnetopenauth

I'm writing my own OpenId provider using DotNetOpenAuth. This provider will only be used by a Relying Party from each of my own sites. In other words it's a closed provider. As such I want to customise the OP so that it only authenticates under certain circumstances as follows.

When site/relying party #1 authenticates the user has to merely pass the authentication challenge.

When site/relying party #2 authenticates the user has to pass the authentication challenge but also has to already have some other data existing as retrieved by the OP.

It's fine for the RP to tell the OP about the requirement. How should I implement this?

Should I use some sort of custom PAPE (how do I do that?) or perhaps through Attribute Exchange (how do I do that?) or some other way (how do I do that?)

Answer (score 0):

The RP may ask of the OP for additional information about the authenticating user via AX.  That's probably the simplest and most appropriate way to do it.  The relevant classes in DotNetOpenAuth to use AX for this is `FetchRequest` and `FetchResponse`.

You can cause your OP to only respond to auth requests from your whitelisted RPs by checking the `IHostProcessedRequest.Realm` property at the OP, and adding additional assurance by checking the `IHostProcessedRequest.IsReturnUrlDiscoverable()` method returns `RelyingPartyDiscoveryResult.Success`.